# VSTO Outlook called by Excel?

Tags: .net, vsto, office-interop

I have an Outlook VSTO 4 AddIn developed by me functioning 100%. It's a XML version of VSTO, not the default sample project.

Today, while running my Outlook, I called EXCEL (Office 365 local mode) and suddenly I saw an error in Excel mentioning fail in GetCustomID procedure, which is present in my Outlook AddIn.

Anyway, my AddIn just have the default Office Tools and Outlook specifically libraries (nothing of Excel is there).

Questions:

- is this fail related to my AddIn, even it is developed and implemented ONLY in Outlook? How can Excel "see" this event on my Outlook? The SUPLEMENTS of Excel does not show my Addin name.
- how can I retrieve the name of Office application in my code to avoid the ribbon be loaded by another Office application than Outlook?

I'm really confused with this behaviour.

I had to disable Excel "Visual Studio Tools for Office Design-Time Adaptor for Excel"

Note: Word does NOT show the same behaviour than Excel.

I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just tried to automate Excel or open an Excel workbook from Outlook. When you do so Excel add-ins are loaded as well as Outlook add-ins. In that case you may get the ribbon UI error message too. There is a know issue in the latest Excel version, see [A bad sample from the VSTO team (Microsoft)](https://eugene-astafiev.blogspot.com/2018/05/ribbon-error-in-excel-vsto-adapter.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you Eugene but my AddIn is NOT trying to open Excel or Word from Outlook. I neither have a Reference to them... I really don't know why this. And my VSTO is cheking only Outlook events to load - although the RibbonExtension is called in a default way.

Comment: Another interesting thing: when I called Excel I made it separetely from Outlook. I mean, I was working and at some moment I called Excel and the error rised... Tks Eugene.